# Only show pictures

Tags: php

I have this script:

```
    $uploadsDirectory = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) .'/slides/head/';  
if ($handle = opendir($uploadsDirectory)) {
    $uplo = array();
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    array_push($uplo, $file);}
    sort($uplo,SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
    $user = array();
foreach($uplo as $fname) {  
if($fname != ".." && $fname != "."){
if(substr($fname,0,1) != "_")
    echo "<div class='bgitem' id='head'>$fname</div>";
else
    array_push($user, "$fname");}}
    closedir($handle);}
```

It works fine, but how can I make it so it only shows the pictures? (I have other files that aren't photos, so it displays a broken picture instead.)

Comment: Why not make a filter array with acceptable extensions?

Comment: `if ($fname is a picture) { display it }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to have it test whether the file is an image in the same line where you test if the file is a parent directory or the current directory (`if($fname != ".." && $fname != "."){`)

You can use `getimagesize()` to determine if the file is any kind of image. If it is not an image, it will return zero.

```
    $uploadsDirectory = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) .'/slides/head/';  
if ($handle = opendir($uploadsDirectory)) {
    $uplo = array();
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    array_push($uplo, $file);}
    sort($uplo,SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
    $user = array();
foreach($uplo as $fname) {  
if($fname != ".." && $fname != "." && getimagesize($fname) != 0){ //Tests if file is an iamge
if(substr($fname,0,1) != "_")
    echo "<div class='bgitem' id='head'>$fname</div>";
else
    array_push($user, "$fname");}}
    closedir($handle);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for you:

```
$extension = explode(".", $fname);
$extension = (isset($extension) && count($extension) > 0)?strtolower($extension[count($extension) -1]):null;

if(in_array($extension, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'])){
    //Show the image

}else{
    //dont show image
}
```